# Updating SPField.SchemaXML has no effect?

Tags: sharepoint

I have been at this for two days. I dont understand why there is no effect is SPField.SchemaXML. I was hoping any help so that I can have a new direction.

```
SPList spList = web.Lists.GetList(new Guid(listGuid), false);
SPField field;  
field = spList.Fields["Description"];
field.SchemaXML = strXML; // No changes to field.SchemaXML???
```

Comment: And the obvious question would be, do you call `field.Update();` after you've done the changes to the *local* `SPField` object?

Comment: Yes, I did... But field.SchemaXML retains its original value before field.Update() is ever called..

Comment: And after it's called, no change to the actual field?

Comment: Nope ... no changes are reflected... Now I am thinking its because of contenttypes as 'Required' is not provided in columnlevel in sharepoint as well. It can be changed in sharepoint using contentypes though

Answer (score 0):

I know this is really old, but isn't the property called SchemaXml (note the case)?